# What does this code mean: currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';

Tags: java

I have a Java assignment and I have to code a FourInARow game, however I searched for some help in the internet and found this code:

```
currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
```

Can anyone please tell me what it actually means?

Thanks ^^

I was trying to understand that line of code but didn't know

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator

Comment: Like mentioned above, `?` followed by `:` is a ternary expression. In your example, the code is designed to change the value of `currentPlayer` to `'X'`, unless the value is already `'X'`. In that case, it sets it to `'O'`. This will bounce back and forth if the code is run multiple times.

Comment: [Search Stack Overflow](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20question%20mark%20and%20colon&tts=st_asaf_macos) thoroughly before posting.

Comment: @BasilBourque sorry dude

Comment: It's official name from the JLS is the conditional operator.